# TinyXML2 and C++

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, tinyxml

I want to read the data from a wxGrid and write it into a XML File.
The wxGrid is like:

> Jahr | Monat
>   ------ |-------------
>   2012 | 03
>   2009 | 08

What I want to have:

```
<SQL>
    <Datensatz>
        <Jahr>2012</Jahr>
        <Monat>03</Monat>
    </Datensatz>
    <Datensatz>
        <Jahr>2009</Jahr>
        <Monat>08</Monat>
    </Datensatz>
</SQL>
```

What I got:

```
<SQL>
    <Datensatz>
        <Jahr>20122009</Jahr>
        <Monat>0308</Monat>
    </Datensatz>
    <Datensatz>
        <Jahr>20122009</Jahr>
        <Monat>0308</Monat>
    </Datensatz>
</SQL>
```

My Code:

```
XMLDocument doc;
XMLElement* xesql = doc.NewElement("SQL");
XMLNode * xnsql = doc.InsertFirstChild(xesql);
XMLElement* xejahr = doc.NewElement("Jahr");
XMLElement* xemonat = doc.NewElement("Monat");
XMLText* datensatzJahr = doc.NewText("");
XMLText* datensatzMonat = doc.NewText("");
for(int i=0; i<=1; i++)
{
    XMLElement* xedatensatz = doc.NewElement("Datensatz");
    datensatzJahr = doc.NewText(m_gd_data->GetCellValue(i,0));
    datensatzMonat = doc.NewText(m_gd_data->GetCellValue(i,1));
    xejahr->InsertEndChild(datensatzJahr);
    xemonat->InsertEndChild(datensatzMonat);
    xedatensatz->InsertEndChild(xejahr);
    xedatensatz->InsertEndChild(xemonat);
    xesql->InsertEndChild(xedatensatz);
}
doc.SaveFile(path);
```

I really don't know where's the problem. Can anyone help?

Comment: what about if you debug it step by step? you should get a clear view as to what's going on as you're getting values for each variables, should be easy to trace.

Comment: Maybe as a general remark, you should use English variable names. For those readers/maintainers of your code that are not German.

Comment: @AlexandruC. +1, it was really hard to read your code for non a German (it is, right?) reader. Is it common in Germany to name variables and functions in German?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not resetting the XML elements for each iteration of the loop, hence you are only appending text to an existing element. this should work:

```
XMLDocument doc;
XMLElement* xesql = doc.NewElement("SQL");
XMLNode * xnsql = doc.InsertFirstChild(xesql);
for(int i=0; i<=1; i++)
{
    XMLElement* xejahr = doc.NewElement("Jahr");
    XMLElement* xemonat = doc.NewElement("Monat");
    XMLText* datensatzJahr = doc.NewText("");
    XMLText* datensatzMonat = doc.NewText("");

    XMLElement* xedatensatz = doc.NewElement("Datensatz");
    datensatzJahr = doc.NewText(m_gd_data->GetCellValue(i,0));
    datensatzMonat = doc.NewText(m_gd_data->GetCellValue(i,1));
    xejahr->InsertEndChild(datensatzJahr);
    xemonat->InsertEndChild(datensatzMonat);
    xedatensatz->InsertEndChild(xejahr);
    xedatensatz->InsertEndChild(xemonat);
    xesql->InsertEndChild(xedatensatz);
}
doc.SaveFile(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create new elements for the year and month inside the loop.